# How can I store a Java HashMap<String,Double> in mongodb using Morphia?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a user defined class **CostMatrix** this class contains two properties and data type for both properties is HashMap. I am using Morphia to communicate with mongodb so my entity class looks like this

```
 @Entity(value = "CostMatrix",noClassnameStored = false)
    public class CostMatrix {
        @Id
        private String id;

        private HashMap<String,Double> distances;

        private HashMap<String,Double> durations;
        public CostMatrix(){}

        public CostMatrix(String id, HashMap<String,Double>distances, HashMap<String,Double>durations) {
            this.id = id;
            this.distances = distances;
            this.durations = durations;
}
```

I am unable to store object properly into database object is stored any how but when I retrieve its just returns id and class name any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the saved document look like from the Mongo shell?

Answer (score 0):

Just add getters for the class members.  It's not related to them being maps, it handles maps just like it handles objects (the keys are the object properties, the values are the values).

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want to have any class/package names in your collection just put the noClassnameStored flag to true.

```
@Entity(value = "CostMatrix",noClassnameStored =**true**)
```

As for the saving part, do you fill some values into your maps? The mapper will ignore null values and empty lists.